# Having Trouble with Gimp's tools box

Tags: gimp

I accidentally dragged part of the Gimp tool box into a bad place and it created a small window that had tool options that I would normally use to change the size and aspect ratio of my paintbrush. Then I clicked the red X on the top right corner of that window, thinking it would just go back to where it was Because I couldn't put it back, It did not reappear and Now I cant get it to appear at all. I have reopened Gimp several times and looked for other answers regarding resetting the toolbox window and my paintbrush editor will not come back no matter what I do. 
Id rather not reinstall Gimp to fix this as I am afraid Ill lose all my art progress.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Toolbox` window currently looks like this:

[image]

Double-click on the paintbrush icon in the `Toolbox` window.  The `Tool Options` window appears:

[image]

In the `Tool Options` window, click on the small triangle-in-a-box, just below the window's title bar.  (In this picture, it's below the `X` that closes the window.)  In the pop-up menu that appears, make sure that the `Lock Tab to Dock` option does not have a checkmark beside it.  If there is a checkmark there, click on `Lock Tab to Dock` to remove the checkmark.  Otherwise, click on the desktop to make the pop-up menu disappear.

At the bottom of the `Tool Options` window, look for a mostly-blank area that says "You can drop dockable dialogues here".  If you don't see that text, drag the bottom of the window frame down a bit.

Click-and-drag the `Tool Options` tab (not the title bar, but the tab immediately below it) and drop it into the bottom part of the `Toolbox` window.  The `Toolbox` window should now include the `Tool Options` tab:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It worked.